# Error when defining resistance values with parameters

Tags: resistors, ltspice

I'm trying to run this simulation but I'm getting an error (see image). I'm using brackets to define the parameters, so I don't understand what's wrong.
[image: Simulation with the error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RE2, RE3, RE4 and R4 have a resistance value of R2 which is supposed to be defined somewhere in the simulation.

Define R2 with `.param` or something else e.g. `.param R2 500`